# Nodejs not starting web service for office addin

Tags: node.js, office365, yeoman-generator

Recently I jumped into creating office web add-ins and have created a couple using visual studio. But now, I have to change to creating add-in using NodeJS. I followed the official Microsoft instruction for the Yeoman generator and the installation works fine until I run

> npm start

This logs.

```
C:\Users\***\source\secondapp>npm start

> office-addin-taskpane-js@0.0.1 start
> office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml

Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in b56ba8a6-675d-44bd-8182-0822410ef349. Debug method: 0
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Debugging started.

C:\Users\***\source\secondapp>
```

As you can the web service fails to start. Without giving any errors.

Answer (score 2):

I have guite same situation right now.. just word is open but not started webpack.
I have to start it manually

```
npm run dev-server
```

than I was able to open my addin in MSWord ..

I use to work with it about year and half just by

```
npm start
```

but perhaps after updatin node to node 15.14.. its stops working..
Give a try to start first dev server and than open office

dont forget to check:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=”microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy”
```